# Configuration store variation with React/redux and thunkMiddleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been through many examples to understand how Redux-Thunk works and most the time the store is configured in a various way. I guess there's the old way or the new way but I'm kind of lost. Here is three pattern that I've identified. If someone can explain me the differences between them :

The simple way :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'

    const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()


    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware( thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware));
```

the Official Reddit Async Exemple way ([here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html)) :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware,
      loggerMiddleware
    )
  )
}
```

the old way ?

```
import {compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

const createAppStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState){
    const store = createAppStore(rootReducer, initialState);

    return store;
};
```

From there I have at least four questions :

- Do we still need to use compose ? I only find it in "old" exemple ?
- Is there any differences between `import ReduxThunk from
  'redux-thunk'` and `import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'` ?
- Does the simple way is also correct ?
- I don't understand the `preloadedState` pattern from the Reddit Async Exemple.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for [createStore](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer) is **`createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])`**.

**`preloadedState`** is an initial state you load before you initialize your app. For instance, if you prerender your first page on a server and want to pass app state as a JSON inside your HTML. Sometimes you need to fetch this state asynchronously that is where the second example is useful. You fetch your state and create a store using that state in the callback of your ajax call.
The third argument.

[**`enhancer`**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#store-enhancer) is a higher-order function that composes a store creator to return a new, enhanced store creator. [`applyMiddleware`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/applyMiddleware.md) is a store `enhancer` shipped with redux. If you want to combine multiple store enhancers you need to use [`compose`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md) function.

For instance, [redux-devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) for chrome is an `enhancer` so to use it in your app you would need `compose` function

```
let store = createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
));
```

When you `import something from 'redux-thunk'` you use `default export` so you can name your variable as you want. It doesn't matter.

A simple way is also correct if you don't need anything fancy it would work just fine.

Comment: Ok cool. thanks. At least that solve my Redux-Devtools issue :)